# Xamarin Android - Build failed after migration to AndroidX

Tags: xamarin.android, androidx

I'm facing a build issue after migration to AndroidX. I encountered following error when build android project:

```
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.1 directly to project WhiteLabel.Mobile.App.Android to resolve this issue. 
Project.Mobile.App.Android -> Xamarin.Essentials 1.2.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (>= 28.0.0.1) 
Project.Mobile.App.Android -> CarouselView.FormsPlugin 5.2.0 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 25.4.0.2). Project.Mobile.App.Android  C:\mprojects\mproject-xamarin\Project.Mobile.App\Project.Mobile.App.Android\Project.Mobile.App.Android.csproj
```

I tried to resolve this with installing latest stable version of *Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat* package with version 28.0.0.3. However, install failed with rolling back package changes in xamarin android project. As of now, I still have no clues on how to fix this, does anyone has any ideas?

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 version 16.6.2
Compile using Android version (Target Framework): Android 10.0(Q)   
Minimum Android version: Android 7 (API level 24 - Nougat)
Target Android version: Android 10.0 (API Level 29 - Q)
Xamarin.Forms: 4.6.0.800
Xamarin.Android Sdk: 10.3.1.4
Xamarin.iOS: 13.18.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` nuget,then could see its **Dependencies**.You could try to install the dependencies it needs according different mono android versions first,then install the `Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat` nuget.

[image]